# Visual Workflow customization

Tags: visual-workflow

I have had a number of clients asking about Visual Workflow. Most questions so far have to do with:

- How do I upload files?
- How do I show related tasks and cases to the lookup I just completed

The only thing I have come up with so far is using JavaScript to interrogate the DOM to pull reference ID's after a lookup has been completed. Same idea would be applied to know which record to attach a file to. I would do this by binding the submit button on an embedded flow in a visualforce page.

This seems awfully hackish, anyone have any better ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can embed Flows in Visualforce Pages as you said.

This would allow you to upload files as part of a flow. The upload of the Attachment or Document would sit outside the flow in the VF Page, and the ParentID for the Attach/Document you could pull from the Record ID's out of the Flow via the Apex Controller.

The Visualforce Pages Controller has access to the Fields (Attributes / Variables) in your Flow.

This would enable you to both perform the File Uploads and Display the related Tasks & Accounts as  components in the VF Page alongisde the flow, populating as appropriate from values in the Flow.

This approach would not require you to do a hack with Javascript.

Comment: awesome, perfect. guess its time to go read the docs more thoroughly.

Comment: Here's a simple example of a Flow that interacts with other elements on the page: http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2011/10/dynamic-visualforce-and-visual-workflow-with-rerender.html